# pd.DataFrame prints output in a single column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a file which I'm trying to convert into data frame using pandas. It is inside a loop and returns me the output as shown below. Here is the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
with open('File.tbl', 'r') as  f:
    P=list(f)
    del P[0]
for o in P:
    M=o.split()
    B= M[:4]             #selecting specific columns only
    E= pd.DataFrame(B)   #converting into DataFrame
    print(E)
    G.to_csv('para.csv', sep=',')
```

Here the tbl file is not tab seperated and to create a tab separation, I've to convert it into list. Here is the reult I'm getting:

```
0    B
1  244
2    S
3    0
     0
0    B
1  245
2    A
3    0
```

The expected output is like this:

```
0    B   244  S  0

0    B   245  A  0
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
df=pd.DataFrame()
with open('File.tbl', 'r') as  f:
    P=list(f)
    del P[0]
for o in P:
    M=o.split()
    B= M[:4]             #selecting specific columns only
    df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(B).T])    #converting into DataFrame
df.to_csv('para.csv', sep=',')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, This is the result I'm getting:                                                      
 0  B  244  S  0
      0    1    2  3
0  B  245  A  0  Any idea how to remove those 0,1, 2, 3.

Comment: @Dustrokes Edited mine.

Comment: It worked, but now it's not getting converted into CSV file, the error I'm getting is this:  'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'. I can convert the file using with open statements but would prefer to directly convert it into csv.

Comment: @Dustrokes Edited mine, just viewd SO

Comment: Hey, any idea how to convert the strings into csv file by directly using to_csv command?

Comment: @Dustrokes Yeah, that's what is is doing, the last line has nothing to do with the `to_csv` part, that's just for printing.

Comment: Yeah, I get it, but I wanted to convert it into csv file using to_csv command. If I try to convert the file as you've mentioned, it prints only last line. The final output should be a csv file

Comment: @Dustrokes Now?

Comment: It's still the same thing. Only single last row is printed.

Comment: Hey I got it, just added a null variable and then appended it. Thanks for the help.